# azure mobile client table insert in bulk

Tags: android, sqlite, azure, xamarin

```
// Create a mobile client

MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("AppUrl","AppKey");

//get table 

IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable = client.GetTable<TodoItem>();

//query table 

MobileServiceTableQuery<TodoItem> query = todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
            .Select(todoItem => todoItem.Text)
            .Skip(0).
            .Take(1000);
List<string> items = await query.ToListAsync();
```

I got 1000 rows. Now i want to insert these 1000 records to mobile client in `xamarin`. how do i insert these 1000 rows in bulk in our `sqlite` todotable ?

Comment: to insert big amount of data use transactions, coz otherwise will be too slow. Google it